# Replace variable length substring with a single characher JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping, spaces

My JavaScript accepts a comma separated list of names and I am putting those names in an array. The names are allowed to have spaces in them, but I want to allow only one space between two words(but not only two in a name as a name can have multiple words in it).

If it were only a fixed number of spaces, it would have been easy to figure that out, but with variable number of spaces I am confused of how to do it.

Here is an example:

```
var arr = ["time", "my name is        something", "hello world"];
```

In the above array I want to replace the extra spaces from the "my name is        something" element with only a single space.

What I have tried so far is counting the number of spaces in each element inside a for loop. If the number of spaces is more than one I am skipping them and in the end appending the rest of the substring to the substring traversed so far.

I wonder if it can be done using some regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (replacing multiple spaces `\s+` with one `' '`

```
var arr = ["time", "my name is        something", "hello world"];
arr = arr.map(function(i){
    return i.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
});
```